# Countifs column A contains "String" & column B starts with "0"

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I need to create a countifs column A contains "String" & column B starts with "0:".

So far I have the following rows:

```
|    A    |  B   |
|  dada   |  0   |
|  String |  0   |
|  dada   |  1   |
```

So that would mean that the only row that would be counted is row 2 which would give us a count of 1 since in row A it contains "String" and in Column B it starts with "0:".

I have the following, but keep ending up with a value of 0 for my count:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*" & "String" & "*",B:B, "*" & "0:" & "*")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using D:D in your formula - is that the correct column?

Comment: Yeah, I just fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To match your description

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*string*",B:B,"0:*")`

...but in your example you have just zero in column B, so that won't be counted because it doesn't start with `"0:"`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a sumproduct:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("400",A:A))*(LEFT(D:D,1)="0"))
```

Mind you, your formula doesn't match your dataset.

Comment: For some reason this works, but it only takes into account all the "400" in column A, but not the 0 in column D. I realize that formula is different, but that was just copy and pasting errors.

Comment: If your 0 is a number rather than a string, try `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("400",A:A))*(D:D=0))`.

Comment: It's actually a time like 0:00

Comment: if it's a time then do you mean you want to include all times which are >= `0:00` and < `01:00`? If so try `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*string*",B:B,">=0:00",B:B,"<1:00")`